# Animation does not work GeoJSON date fields in CARTO VL

Tags: geojson, carto, animation, carto-vl

In CARTO VL [`linear`](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/reference/#cartoexpressionslinear) function expects a date or numeric field as its first argument. But when the data source is a GeoJSON, date fields are stored as categorical/strings and it returns an error like this:

```
CartoValidationError: [Property with an incorrect type]: linear(): invalid first parameter 'input' expected type was one of number,date, actual type was 'category'
```

You can test it in [this visualizer](https://carto-vl-visualizer.glitch.me) replacing the current CARTO VL viz style with something like:

```
 filter: animation(
             linear(
                    $date,
                    time('2019-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
                    time('2019-01-31T00:00:00Z')
                ),
                20,
                fade(0.5, 0.5))
```

Is there any workaround to convert this (string/categorical) date field to a proper date/timestamp field in CARTO VL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GeoJSON source method has an option to indicate the 'date' columns.

Can you try with something like this?

```
const dateColumns = ['date'];
const options = { dateColumns };
const newSource = new carto.source.GeoJSON(JSON.parse(this.source), options);
```

:wave

Comment: Thanks Victor! :magic: